# full calendar Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am making website using full calendar. However, It works fine until yesterday, but today I have an Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

**Console Error**

[image]

**HTML**

[image]

Comment: this will be a server permissions problem, nothing to do with fullCalendar. You should not be using fullcalendar.io as a CDN though, it's not designed for that. The files on the fullCalendar website are for running demos on the fullCalendar site. The site's capacity doesn't scale to delivering them for everyone else. You may have been blocked for requesting them too many times, perhaps, I don't know. Anyway, source your files from CDNJS as recommended in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/download

Answer (score -1):

I advise you download npm and install fullcalendar, that way you won't run into these issues, since you will have the files locally.

https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

https://fullcalendar.io/download

Comment: Now, I tested my html file with localhost, then weirdly, I do not have any problem now..